# Python3 error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my Python3 program.

```
try:
    while true:
        A
except NewConnectionError:
    print('error detection')
```

I thought when above program catches NewConnectionError it goes back to "A" after printing a log. But it doesn't.

How do I change above codes to restart "A" recursively when the program catching Error.

Thanks.

P.S. 
Not only restarting, but keeping running is also good for me.
Thanks for quickly replying.

Comment: Your code formatting is broken completely. Please [edit] and fix it.

Comment: Why recursively?

Comment: When program catches error, I want to keep it runnning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the try/except blocks inside the while loop (not the other way around):

```
while True:
    try:
        A()
    except NewConnectionError as err:
        # This will also print the reason the exception occurred
        print ('Detected error: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print("A() returned successfully.")
    finally:
        print ("Next loop iteration...")
```

You can safely omit the `else` and `finally` blocks. I have only included them for illustrative purposes.

`else` is only executed if an exception does NOT occur (that is, if the statements in the try block were successful).

`finally` is always executed regardless whether an exception occurs or not.

Answer (score -2):

you need to place while above the try method so your code would be something like this:

```
while true
   try
   -------
   except
   --------
```